# Handle NULL value in Nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

Nested query returns NULL(value of t), but I want to return 0 instead of NULL, so I added case condition. but still this query returns NULL

```
select case when t.a is NULL then 0 else t.a end 
from

(select QTIB_REQ_ as a from qb_requisitions_all 
where  QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA) 
and CLIENT___BENCH___NON_BILLABLE IN ( 'Non Billable', 'Non-Billable', 'NonBillable') 
and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE)<30 
and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE)>0) as t
```

Comment: you can give a try with "case when t.a is NULL or t.a = '' then 0 else t.a end"

Comment: returns NULL, please let me know if you have any other logic

Answer (score 0):

`IFNULL()` function lets you return an alternative value if an expression is `NULL`. Try this:

```
select IFNULL(QTIB_REQ_, 0) as a from qb_requisitions_all 
where  QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA) 
and CLIENT___BENCH___NON_BILLABLE IN ( 'Non Billable', 'Non-Billable', 'NonBillable') 
and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE)<30 
and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE)>0
```

Comment: not working, it returns null. but for else condition its working

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery *cannot* return `NULL` for `t.a`.  Why not?  Because you have the condition:

```
QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA)
```

You are returning the value of `QTIB_REQ_` and a `NULL` value cannot match this condition.

I can think of two possibilities.  Perhaps you mean `'NULL'` and not `NULL`.  If so, the logic should be:

```
select (case when t.a is NULL or t.a = 'NULL' then '0 'else t.a end)
```

However, this seems unlikely because the `0` suggests that the value is a number.

Alternatively, you really have a correlated subquery but you "simplified" it for the question.  So you really have:

```
select (select QTIB_REQ_ as a
        from qb_requisitions_all 
        where QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA) and
              CLIENT___BENCH___NON_BILLABLE IN ( 'Non Billable', 'Non-Billable', 'NonBillable') and
              DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) < 30 and 
              DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) > 0
       )
```

If this is the case, your problem is that the subquery is returning no rows, so the value is interpreted as `NULL`.  You can fix this using `COALESCE()` or by using aggregation and `COALESCE()`.  Because this should return at most one row, I would go for:

```
select (select coalesce(max(QTIB_REQ_), 0) 
        from qb_requisitions_all 
        where QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA) and
              CLIENT___BENCH___NON_BILLABLE IN ( 'Non Billable', 'Non-Billable', 'NonBillable') and
              DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) < 30 and 
              DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) > 0
       )
```

Comment: your logic is superb! but it returns only max value which is not the requirement. I want to display all the values, i tried removing max function but its not working. It would be of great help if you can guide me

Comment: @ravishraja . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *new* question, with a clear explanation, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285777/handle-null-value-in-nested-query-mysql