# Handle NULL value in nested query mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace NULL with 0 with the below query.
but when the result is not NULL, it fetches onlY the max value which is not the requirement.
I tried removing max function but it returns NULL.

Below is the query.

```
select (select coalesce(max(QTIB_REQ_), 0) 
  from qb_requisitions_all 
 where QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA) 
   and CLIENT___BENCH___NON_BILLABLE IN ( 'Non Billable', 'Non-Billable', 'NonBillable') 
   and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) < 30 
   and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) > 0
   )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: SELECT COALESCE (SELECT value, o)), you must embrace your inner select with external coalesce

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding IFNULL inside max aggregate

```
select (select max(IFNULL(QTIB_REQ_, 0))
from qb_requisitions_all 
where QTIB_REQ_ IN ($Req_disabled_WA) and CLIENT___BENCH___NON_BILLABLE IN ( 'Non 
 Billable', 'Non-Billable', 'NonBillable') 
 and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) < 30 
 and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),TARGET_FILL_DATE) > 0
```